# Is it legal to record a phone conversation if you pretend to be someone else?

Tags: privacy, recording, phonecall, russia

In a recently published [video](https://youtu.be/ibqiet6Bg38), Alexey Navalny [calls](https://apnews.com/article/alexei-navalny-poisoning-underpants-202f470c2d1c19151b9deb564d94e8f9) one of the [FSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Security_Service)'s operatives who participated in Navalny's poisoning, and, pretending to be his colleague, manages to record some evidence about the operation.

Now, Russia apparently is one of the [one-party consent countries](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/russia-supreme-court-rules-on-phone-46821/), where secretly recording a conversation you hold with someone is not illegal by itself. However, I would expect that to change is the other party is led to believe they are speaking with someone else.

I understand the circumstances are quite extraordinary, however, I think the legality of the recording is still a crucial aspect. Could Navalny face charges for releasing it, and would it be admissible as evidence in a court case?

Comment: I suppose there is a law in Russia about phone recordings, and the law doesn't just state "Russia is a one-party consent country".

Comment: The linked summary says that such recordings may be admissible evidence, which is not the same as saying they are lawful. I cannot speak for the Russian rules of court, but in England and Wales any material obtained illegally *may* be admissible evidence in the interests of justice.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sure there is. However, I expect such laws in one-party consent countries to be somewhat similar, which may be close enough for educational purposes. Of course I'm not trying to crowd-source actual legal advice here.